# Scikit-learn: Strong imbalance between false-positives and false-negatives

Tags: optimization, scikit-learn, classification, evaluation, false-positive

Using `scikit-learn` on balanced training data of around 50 millions samples (50% one class, 50% the other, 8 continuous features in interval `(0,1)`), all classifiers that I have been able to try so far (Linear/LogisticRegression, `LinearSVC`, `RandomForestClassifier`, ...) show a strange behavior:

When testing on the training data, the percentage of false-positives is much lower than the percentage of false-negatives (fnr). When correcting the intercept manually in order to increase false-positive rate (fpr), the accuracy actually improves considerably.

Why do the classification algorithms not find a close-to-optimal intercept (that I guess would more or less be at fpr=fnr)?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, with not enough fnr  or tnr.

Comment: Logistic regression optimizes the log loss.  The log loss might be minimized in a situation with high false negatives, or in a situation with high false positives, or in a situation with low accuracy, it just depends on what your data are like.  If you want to optimize accuracy, then optimize accuracy instead of log loss.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the idea is that there's no single definition of "optimal"; for some applications, you'll tolerate false positives much more than false negatives (i.e. detecting fraud or disease where you don't want to miss a positive) whereas for other applications false positives are much worse (predicting equipment failures, crimes, or something else where the cost of taking action is expensive). By default, `predict` just chooses `0.5` as the threshold, this is usually not what you want, you need think about your application and then look at the ROC curve and the gains/lift charts to decide where you want to set the prediction threshold.